# Flash input box works fine when I test movie, but the SWF does not take in input

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an input text box (classic text) in my flash movie, which works absolutely fine when I test the movie using Ctrl+Enter. However, when I try to play the published SWF file, the input box does not accept any text. I do see the cursor and can click into the input box, but it doesn't show anything that I enter.

Any ideas why this might be? :) Also, I'm not getting any errors while compiling the movie using Ctrl+Enter.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use any non-standard Fonts for that textbox? If yes, then that is the most likely issue. Embed the necessary fonts and republish your SWF.

Comment: Hi, I am using non-standard fonts, but I did click on Embed in properties and OK in the Embed popup box.Also, I tried changing it to standard font (Verdana) but I still have the same issue, irrespective of font